# В vs code ломается путь к исполняемому файлу python.exe

Tags: visual-studio-code

Периодически выдает такую ошибку. И следующие кидает в консоль. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно исправить? По мимо переустановки "vs code". И из-за чего это может происходить?

PS C:\Users\Илья\Documents\xxx> & C:/Users/лья/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/лья/Documents/xxx/FTP_test_LOGIN.py
& : Имя "C:/Users/лья/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:3

- & C:/Users/лья/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/ ...
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/лья/Ap...n311/python.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Да снесите вы текущий и установите Python в C:\Python3, чтобы в пути отсутствовали бы русские буквы.